# How to Add Win/Loss Counter to Rock Paper Scissors Program

Tags: python

I have pretty much finished this Rock Paper Scissors program, but one of the final steps is to add a counter to print the Win, Loss, and Tie ratio after the user is done playing.

I tried in the `count_win_loss()` function to enumerate the messages index that I pass to it in the `play_game()` function, but all it is returning zeros

```py
import random
def count_win_loss(messages_from_result):
    player_wins = 0
    cpu_wins = 0
    ties = 0
    #This is supposed to get the index value position of this list, which 
    should be defined at the end of `play_game()` function.
    for index in enumerate(messages_from_result):
        new_index = index
    #NOT WORKING NEEDS TO BE FIXED
    if new_index == 0:
        ties += 1
    elif new_index == 1:
        player_wins += 1
    elif new_index == 2:
        cpu_wins += 1
    else:
        ties += 0
        player_wins += 0
        cpu_wins += 0
    #NOT WORKING NEEDS TO BE FIXED
    print(player_wins)
    print(cpu_wins)
    print(ties)
    #print('\nHuman Wins: %d, Computer Wins: %d, Ties: %d' % (player_wins, cpu_wins, ties))
```

This `elif` statement appears at the end of my game function. It executes when a user inputs '2' which ends the loop.

```py
       #Creates a format that can be passed to the results matrix.
       #Additionally creates an index 3 that I will reference as the error value.
            guesses_index = guess_dict.get(user_guess, 3)
            computer_index = guess_dict.get(computer_guess)
            result_index = results[guesses_index][computer_index]
            final_result = result_messages[result_index]
        
        elif play_again == '2':
            count_win_loss(result_messages) #NOT WORKING NEED HELP
            print('Thanks for playing!')
            continue_loop = False
```

I pass it this messages list:

```py
result_messages = [
        "You tied!", 
        "You win!", 
        "The Computer won. :(", 
        "Invalid weapon, please try again."
    ]
```

As mentioned in the title, I need a win/loss counter, which I thought my `calc_win_loss()` would do

Answer (score 1):

New_Index variable is not defined inside this function, therefore global to where ever you defining the value and get in the starting of this function 
For ex:- 
         `def a():

             b = 2

         def c():                                                                                                                                   .              print(b)`                                                                                                                 . Whenever you will call c() it will cause an error because b is a local variable
in side function a() however if you do 
         `def a():
            global b

            b = 2
         def c():
            print(b)`
Now when you call a() and then c(). Th error will go away